# Styling a MapPolygon

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I was going to create a `Style` for `MapPolygon`, but I can't seem to add a `Setter` for anything other than the properties inherited from `Control`, which doesn't help very much since the MapPolygon doesn't actually use many of those properties.

I mainly want to be able to style the `Fill`, `Stroke`, and `StrokeThickness` properties. When I try to do this, however, I get the following error: **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**. Am I correct in thinking this is because the properties that I am trying to style are not dependency properties (`DependencyProperty`)?

If my thinking here is indeed correct, would the easiest way to solve this problem be to create a custom `MapPolygon` control and create dependency properties for `Fill`, `Stroke`, and `StrokeThickness`?

Let me know if I need to clarify something.

**Update:**

```
public class StyledMapPolygon : MapPolygon {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Fill", typeof(Brush), typeof(StyledMapPolygon),
       new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFillChanged)));

    private static void OnFillChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        StyledMapPolygon instance = (StyledMapPolygon) d;
        instance.Fill = e.NewValue as Brush;
    }
}
```

.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomStyle" TargetType="exts:StyledMapPolygon">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BuildingFillBrush}" />
</Style>
```

This is just a simplified version of a style that I would like to use. the `StyledMapPolygon` is a object I created inherited from `MapPolygon`. The only difference is that I created a `DependencyProperty` for "Fill" that just maps to the base property.

The error mentioned above still appears on "Fill" within the `Setter`, but it now works (displays correctly on the phone). I can live with the error there since it still runs, but I would very much like to have my app be error free.

Comment: show your code (especially the line causing the exception) rather than just describing it.

Comment: I updated the question with the progress that I have made. @Matt - My code doesn't really matter all that much. All I want to know is how to correctly set a `MapPolygon`'s Fill property from a `Style`.

Comment: So what you're saying is "How do I do X?". You'll get a lot more help if you can say "I'm trying to do X. I'm doing ... but I have such-and-such problem/exception.".

Comment: In most cases I would agree, but this question seemed simple and general enough that supplying code would be more confusing than helpful. However, I updated the question with code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a property must be a `DependencyProperty` in order to be set by a style.

There's nothing wrong with adding your own dependency property that wraps a property on the base class, but I wouldn't recommend trying to use the same property name. Create a differently named property, with property changed handler which relays the value which is set to the underlying property.

Of course if the "error" you mention is Intellisense there's really no reason to care, so long as code compiles and runs.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on my `DependencyProperty` assumption. The problem with ignoring the error is that I am actually doing the same thing for several other properties, like `Stroke`, `StrokeThickness`, etc., and I have many styles for `StyledMapPolygon`. So I end up with over 60 errors and it makes it hard to see the other errors and warnings that I do need to care about.

Comment: Have you tried using a different property name? I suspect that might be the source of your errors. So try using "MyFill" (or some better name!) as a dependency property that on changed sets the Fill, and use MyFill in the style - it wouldn't be surprising if something got confused between a CLR property and Dependency Property of the same name - that's not the intended way of working.

Comment: Changing the name of the `DependencyProperty` to something other than the regular property's name did remove the error. However, this created a new error saying that it could not find "MyFill" since ti was only a `DependencyProperty` and not a CLR property. So I also have to add another property to remove the second error. Seems like a lot of extra code to remove intellisense errors...